# Don't re-execute Retrofit call if it's still in progress using RxJava 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java

My goal is a method that will execute a network call unless the network call is already in progress in which case the caller subscribes to the results of the existing call.

Here is what I have, it mostly works:

```
private AsyncSubject<Stuff> asyncSubject;

public Observable<Stuff> getStuff() {
    if (asyncSubject == null) {
        asyncSubject = AsyncSubject.create();
        asyncSubject
            .doAfterTerminate(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    asyncSubject = null;
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
        retrofitApi.getStuff()
            .subscribe(asyncSubject);
    }
    return asyncSubject
        .someOperatorsHere();
}
```

This mostly works because asyncSubject nulls itself out on terminate so that any subsequent calls will re-execute the network request.

But there is a bug, there's a window between `if (asyncSubject == null)` and `return asyncSubject` where doAfterTerminate can execute and I get a null pointer.

Any ideas how to fix the bug. Maybe there is a more elegant Rx way to do this? Or `synchronized` block. Or a way to query Retrofit for network progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution shares the subscription between ongoing subscribers.

```
private Observable<Stuff> stuff = retrofitApi.getStuff().share();

public Observable<Stuff> getStuff() {
    return stuff
        .someOperatorsHere();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works if you call it a second time after the network call completes. You have to call retrofitApi.getStuff() again to get it to re-execute the network call.

Comment: Yes. It will call/subscribe again

Comment: I just tested this, it did not work. Calling getStuff() after retrofit sent the first onComplete did not re-execute the network call.

Comment: Can u post the code that is using getStuff()? I was testing this before posting the answer.

Comment: Here's how I tested https://gist.github.com/guelo/74ee2b06f4b314100fc69950592a19c3 The retrofit() observable has a 1 second delay. So the first two .subscribe calls happen before onComplete and the third .subscribe happens afterwards.

Comment: Change `Observable.just` to `Observable.fromCallable` will make the test pass. Using Obsevable.just() will not call `Math.random()` more than 1 time.

Comment: I see. So then the question is if the real Retrofit behaves like `Observable.just` or like `Observable.fromCallable`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it uses `fromcallable`, but it should behave like so. It does in my test

Comment: I tested with real retrofit and it worked. I'm giving you the points. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of possible solutions, I'll just describe the one that is probably simplest in your case.

You have 2 problems: race condition, and nullifying and recreating subject, which is rather unsafe.

What you can do is save your `Subscription` here

```
retrofitApi.getStuff().subscribe(asyncSubject);
```

And instead of checking `if (asyncSubject == null)`, you can check `if (s.isUnsubscribed())`.

So your code will look more or less like this:

```
private AsyncSubject<Stuff> asyncSubject = AsyncSubject.create();
private Subscription subscription = Subscriptions.unsubscribed();

public Observable<Stuff> getStuff() {
    if (subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        subscription = retrofitApi.getStuff()
            .subscribe(asyncSubject);
    }
    return asyncSubject
        .someOperatorsHere();
}
```

Comment: I should have specified in my question that I'm using RxJava 2. I made the change. I guess I can use disposable.isDisposed()

Comment: It didn't really work with disposable.isDisposed() because you can't guarantee the subscription is disposed after onComplete, according to https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5283#issuecomment-294034426

Comment: I suppose I can use a boolean flag instead of nullifying inside  `asyncSubject.doAfterTerminate`. But none of these solutions fix the race condition.